# Test suites in Junit 5

Tags: java, junit5

I have several test classes sharing extending the BaseTest.class as following

```
class BaseTest{

@BeforeAll
static setup(){
// code to setup some configs for tests
  }
}
```

AND

```
class TestClass1 extends BaseTest{

@Test
void test1(){
// test code
  }
}
```

```
class TestClass2 extends BaseTest{

@Test
void test2(){
// test code
  }
}
```

**My need** is to run these two tests in Parallel, but on different parameters passed to **setup()** method in BaseTest class, I found it easy in TestNg using testng.xml, but i need to use Junit5 to achieve this, Example from testng is

```
<suite name="Test-class Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test-class test 1">
         <parameter name="paramName" value="paramValue1" />
        <classes>
            <class name="TestClass1" />
            <class name="TestClass2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test-class test 2">
        <parameter name="paramName" value="paramValue2" />
       <classes>
            <class name="TestClass1" />
            <class name="TestClass2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I want your help to hear some suggestions/ideas how can i achieve this goal using Junit5, I appreciate all you inputs !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you make use of @BeforeEach?

Comment: @BeforeEach does not solve what i need here, i am not sure if my case is clear enough to you

Comment: You could have two separate before-all-methods and extract the shared code into a sharedSetup(configParam) method.